# Power series development of inverse function

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:**

> Let $G=\{z\in \Bbb{C} : | \text{Im }z|< \pi/4, \text{Re }z> \pi/4 -1 \}$ and $f:G\to f(G), z\mapsto z e^z$.
>
> Prove that $f$ is injective on $G$ and compute the first three coefficients $a_0, a_1, a_2$ of the power series development in $0$ of $f^{-1}:f(G)\to G$.

I have proved that $f$ is injective on $G$ but I don't see a way of computing $a_0, a_1, a_2$. How do we go about doing that? Do we try to find an explicit form of the inverse function?

Thankful for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(f^{-1}(z))'=\frac {1}{f'(f^{-1}(z))}$ and from there you can find the other coefficients...